# Getting rid of OneDrive for good

Tags: onedrive

Microsoft forced OneDrive on my W10 PC. I uninstalled it when that happened but my documents and desktop are still in C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents rather than C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents. Because of this I actually had an issue with a CAD installer yesterday where the installer could not find the proper files.

What is the best path forward toward getting rid of OneDrive and getting my documents, desktop and any other files where they should be (C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents, etc.)?

Answer (score 1):

Copy the documents from the One Drive folder to a different C:\Documents folder. Make sure the documents copied properly and you can use them. The point of this is to have a copy outside of One Drive.

Now sign out of One Drive. You might be able to do this in computer One Drive or, more likely, you would need to use your Office Account online.

Once you have signed out of One Dive, delete the documents in "C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Documents ". Do not delete the main One Drive folder.  Make sure all the documents have gone.

Now One Drive comes with Office, so when you are done, One Drive may still be there but with empty folders.  Just ignore it. I have that here and do not have any documents in One Drive.

Here is a screen shot of my One Drive. Empty except for a screen shot I put there a while back. There were a couple of very old and empty folders from a couple of years ago. I just deleted them. No impact at all on "My Documents"

[image]

Comment: Doesn't OneDrive make their OneDrive folder the default? How would I "unwire" this behavior so that my "normal" C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents, etc. folders are my default users folders?

Comment: One Drive has its own set of folders, and on my machines that does not interfere with My Documents general folder. The two are different and my One Drive folders are all empty (both my production computers)  I set my apps to use My Documents and Windows Explorer shows both. I just choose the one  I want.

Comment: I added a screen shot of One Drive showing that it is basically empty and has no impact on "My Documents".

Comment: Since I have Office 365 on multiple computers, I went to my Desktop computer and see that the One Drive (old) folders I deleted were also deleted on my Desktop computer as well. So all is working as I said and no impact on my local documents.

Comment: I guess I was actually asking how to remove documents from the Quick Access - I figured that out. What about Desktop. All the files and folders displayed on my desktop are in the OneDrive version. How do I make my desktop folder default to c:/users/xxxxx/desktop?

Comment: Explorer does not have a default for viewing files but Apps do and that is where you would set the Open defaults. The Quick Access information was newer but QA is not document storage - just links. You can clear QA in QA Options.

Comment: When I minimize all my apps there are a bunch of folders and files that show on my desktop. The folders and files are coming from the C:\Users\xxxxx\OneDrive\Desktop NOT C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop. I am trying to determine how to make the files and folders in C:\Users\xxxxx\Desktop show up on my desktop.

Comment: You wanted to and were supposed to get your One Drive documents into “My Documents “ and clear out One Drive . Open “My Documents “ in Windows Explorer (easy - does not default to One Drive) and then you can put shortcuts to Folders and Files on your Desktop. That should be easy as well.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, your personal folders won't be replaced by these floders synced in OneDrive, as these folders are mirrored folders under the user profile.

I suggest you refer to the article "[How to Restore Default Location of Your Personal Folders in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/23504-restore-default-location-personal-folders-windows-10-a.html)" to restore default location of your personal folders.
[image]

After restoring the location, then you may unpin these folders from Quick Access, location to `C:\Users\xxxxx\`, right click them, pin to Quick Access again.

But based on my test, the folders under "**This PC**" will still show the path of OneDrive.

I am afraid it needs to create a new Windows account to get rid of OneDrive completely.

[image]